# Parse file to get first occurrence of unique lines

Tags: perl

I need to parse a big file (more than 500 MB) and get unique lines.
Indeed I need the first occurrence of unique lines.

Can you please suggest efficient ways to get this done when my RAM is limited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a hash. They are the typical way to dedupe data:

```
my %data;
while (<$fh>) {
    .... # other code
    $data{$key} //= $value;
}
```

The defined-or assignment `//=` operator is the equivalent of doing:

```
if (not defined $data{$key}) {
    $data{$key} = $value;
}
```

This means that only the first value of this key is saved.

Note that the deduping with a hash works only for strings that are exactly identical.

Comment: @david - With sufficient memory, yes. If necessary, split the file into smaller parts, find the unique lines in each part, and then dedupe while merging.

Comment: I actually don't need the key. Is there a way to avoid keys?

Comment: @TLP I've tried:

if (not defined $data{$key}) {
    $data{$key} = $value;
}

But it's not working. :(

Comment: What is `$key`? Don't you just mean `$_`?

Comment: @david "Its not working" tells me nothing. You might as well say "arglebargle". Also, even with 1Gb files, memory should not be a huge issue unless you duplicate data. Have you run into memory problems, or is this just a case of premature optimisation?

Comment: @mob No, I assume it is not the entire line that is the key, but rather a part of it (based on earlier questions).

Comment: @TLP I figured out the problem. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use a hash to keep track of what lines you have already seen.

```
my %seen;
while (<$fh>) {
   next if $seen{$_}++;      # duplicate
   ...
}
```